# Why c# Blazor app don't restart after a reboot server IIS?

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

Last night around 2:00 am the server hsoting my blazor server side app had a reboot.
the reboot went well and IIS retstarted too but I had browse on the web application to make it back alive...

here we can see, on my log(I use Serilog), that the web application is shutting down ...
[image]

And the problem is that I set Job to do every night using Hangfire and because of that reboot, the Job did't start...

How can I make revive, make my blazor web app back alive automatically without I have to browse it on my browser?

Note that I have already set the start mode setting on always running and idle at 0, preload to True and change the Regular Time Interval (minutes) from 1740 to 0.

Comment: *but I had browse on the web application to make it back alive* - does it do something without your attendance? *I have to browse it on my browser?* - which is the normal way to get a websote to do anything, so does it really matter if it goes to sleep? It's like "if a tree falls over in the forest and noone hears it, does it matter if it makes a sound or not?"

Comment: @CaiusJard _does it do something without your attendance_  ?No, it does nothing... but i had to say, you're right, i have a job scheduled in the app working with HangFire and it seems its not waking up except if I wake up the Blazor web App

Comment: Could you please tell me your client will auto reconnect the blazor application or not? Do you set this feature in your application?

Comment: @BrandoZhang sorry I don't know what you are talking about... can you tell me more? Which is the feature that you talk ..? you mean in IIS server or on some part in my Blazor web App?

Comment: I not sure your requirement now.  Do you mean you want to auto warm up the application or let the client reconnect to the server when the server has reboot. I mean the client could have the reconnect feature, if they feel the server drop the connection, they you could try to reconnect to the server.   The blazor contains related things https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-hub-endpoint-route-configuration-blazor-server .

Comment: @BrandoZhang yes i want the blazor web app work as before the reboot of the server without any user action, mean also the scheduled job ... and until now I have to browse my webapp to make it work again by refreshing/revive it ...

Comment: You need to configure the appPool correctly. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/828200/difference-between-start-application-pool-immediately-and-start-mode-alwaysrun

Comment: thanks @Yogi , but like I said in the post, I already configure the appPool correctly like they say on you link ... it seems that it only launches the worker process when the first request for the web application is received, even if i set the _StartMode_ on _AlwaysRunning_ I don't know why...

Comment: As an alternative on Windows servers, you can uses Task Scheduler to trigger a Powershell script that calls your web server.  I used that on a project with good result compared to doing it within IIS with HangFire or other library.  See Powershell [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2) and [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: thank you @Yogi for your advise, can you tell me more on this option? in my case i would like to restart the hangfire's schedule, like i said it seems it need to have a first request on the web application by browse the blazor web app to restart the hangfire's scheduler... so i should maybe try to use Task Scheduler to browse the web app when the server restart? what do you think?, is there a simpliest way ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

iis manager -> sites -> your_blazor_app -> right-click -> manage application -> advance settings -> preload enabled <= set it to "True"